# How to write a stored procedure that recompiles all the PL/SQL packages

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, package, database-administration, db2-luw

I am trying to write a stored procedure to recompile all the PL/SQL packages created in DB2.

I have a number of PL/SQL packages in which multiple stored procedures are introduced. e.g.,

```
create or replace package packagename 
is 
  procedure procedurename; 
end packagename;
```

I want to compile these packages from stored procedures in other packages, because there are stored procedures which change table definitions like adding columns to tables, etc. In order to avoid any cache issues, I want them to recompile.

Is there a way to compile such stored procedures programmatically?

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem to me. Why do you think you need to 1) rebind system packages and 2) do that from a stored procedure?

Comment: I just want to compile application procedures excluding system procedures. But couldn`t find separate commands and found only mentioned commands which compiles all.

please suggest if its possible to compile application procedures alone.

Comment: Please give an example of "compiling application procedures", because until now you have been only talking about binding packages, which is a different thing.

Comment: Sorry, but it's getting even more confusing. Please give example of introducing multiple stored procedures in an embedded SQL package. Normally you would not have a bind file for an SQL stored procedure; its package is created during compilation and stored directly in a catalog table.

Comment: Sorry Mustaccio, i mean 'Embedded SQL packages' in which multiple stored procedures are introduced.

e.g., create or replace package packagename is
   procedure procedurename;
end packagename;

I want to compile these packages from stored procedures in another packages. Because there are stored procedures which changes table definitions like adding columns to tables, etc. In order to avoid any cache issues, i want them to recompile.

Being a newbie, may be i am wrong in technical terms used.Sorry for that.Please let me know by any change is there a way to compile such stored procedures

Comment: You are confusing PL/SQL packages and DB2 plan packages -- these are different things. Is this what you're looking for: [ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053626.html?pos=2)

Comment: Oh yes! I was confused between those. And yes i am looking for ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS . Thanks a lot

Comment: I took a liberty of restating your question based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system stored procedure [ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053626.html?pos=2) that can be called to revalidate (that is, recompile) objects that were made invalid by changed dependencies.